# is_logged_in not working after login

Tags: login

I am using `is_user_logged_in()` after a user has logged in to woocommerce (the page is a replacement for the user's woocommerce dash).  This returns false, though if I reload the page it returns true.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similiar problem that user seemed to be logged out after getting redirected after login. After refreshing the page or navigating to another page user would be logged in.

A comment I saw here, [Logging in redirects to correct page but shows logged out content until forced refresh](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/257721/logging-in-redirects-to-correct-page-but-shows-logged-out-content-until-forced-r#comment383993_257721), helped me to solve the problem.

I used [add_query_arg](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_query_arg/) to add a dummy parameter to bust browser cache, which I think was the root problem. I placed the following code inside my redirection function's conditions check,

```
$redirect = add_query_arg( 'redirect', time(), home_url() );
wp_redirect( $redirect );
exit();
```

Of course the key and the value can be anything.